# Is it possible to select/update shape/icons/image properties using MS powerpoint add-in?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

Using this sample code in MS powerpoint office add-in from Script-Lab, setSelectedDataAsync is able to insert an Svg.

```
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(
    getImageAsBase64String(),
    {
      coercionType: Office.CoercionType.XmlSvg,
      imageLeft: 50,
      imageTop: 50,
      imageWidth: 400
    },
    function(asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        console.error(asyncResult.error.message);
      }
    }
  );
```

Note: getImageAsBase64String() is a function that returns a string. Not copying here explicitly.

However, when I tried to access the inserted Svg, the following code throws error : "The specified coercion type is not supported."

```
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.XmlSvg, function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
      console.error(asyncResult.error.message);
    } else {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(asyncResult.value, null, 4));
    }
  });
```

I have tried selecting images, icons, Svg, text etc. and modifying CoercionType appropriately. I was able to successfully get text only from the rectangular box I inserted. I couldn't find anything to fill that text box with a different color. The documentation for powerpoint add-in using office.js is very limited.

I would like to know if it is possible to select/update shape/icons/image properties using MS powerpoint add-in.

Comment: The documentation [getSelectedDataAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/office/office.document#getSelectedDataAsync_coercionType__callback_) says that CoercionType.XmlSvg is supported by PowerPoint. I suggest you raise this as an [issue on the office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues).

Comment: Indeed I am using XmlSvg right now. Not sure if this is a new thing.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to update the image of an existing shape?

Comment: @user2524908 Not sure if it helps you, but what I ended up doing was to add a specific tag to shapes that I wanted to manage. Then I delete the shape and add the modified one in its place